# Can React be used without JSX?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, preact, infernojs

jsx is used tactically in React and helps developers understand React components by viewing the code in more detail.
Now the question is, is it possible to use other methods such as using simple functions or using other libraries such as preact or inferno in the react library?

With the searches that I did, I think that other libraries such as preact or inferno can be used in the React library.
Is this conclusion correct?

Comment: JSX is just 'syntactic sugar' for `React.createElement`, meaning it's entirely possible and sometimes beneficial to not use JSX

Comment: https://react.dev/reference/react/createElement#creating-an-element-without-jsx

Comment: Preact and Inferno are React alternatives. You cannot use them in React, at least not nicely.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, we can use react without jsx for that we need to use `React.createElement()` everywhere in code. So, anything you can do with JSX can also be done with just `React.createElement()`.

you can do this because jsx is being converted into `React.createElement()` using Babel compiler

Example:

JSX :-

```
<div>Hello Jsx</div>
```

React.createElement :-

`React.createElement('div', null, 'Hello');`